# How to assign serverpath of image to img src

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller

I want to show image in view from database. I store the image path in database so I want to give that path to `img src=""` but it does not work. Code is following:

The following code is in view

```
@{
   var FileName = db.UserImages.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserID == User.Identity.Name).ImgName;
   var serverpath = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/ProfileImages/");
   string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileName);
   string fullpath = Path.Combine(serverpath, filename);

   ViewBag.fullpath = fullpath;
}

<img src="@Url.Content("~/App_Data/ProfileImages/" + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(ViewBag.fullpath))" class="user-image" alt="User Image">
```

The image does not loaded where path is correct but it does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't it just be below since your `fullpath` essentially contains the whole path of the said image file

```
<img src="@Url.Content(ViewBag.fullpath)" class="user-image" alt="User Image">
```

Answer (score 0):

The **Server.MapPath** call will give you a server based file path, ie something like **c:\websites\mywebsite\App_Data\ProfileImages**,  which normally isn't accessable via the web.

From you snippet of code, it appears you just need to combine the cleaned FileName retrieved from the database with **~/App_Data/ProfileImages/**

```
@{
   var FileName = db.UserImages.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserID == User.Identity.Name).ImgName;
   string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileName);
}

<img src="@Url.Content("~/App_Data/ProfileImages/" + filename)" class="user-image" alt="User Image">
```

**edit:** App_Data is a special protected folder that IIS will not serve files from unless configured to do so, look at system.webServer/security/requestFiltering/hiddenSegments

Comment: Is that any other way to do same thing ? any other method ?

Comment: App_Data is a special folder, unless you explicitly configure it, IIS wont allow you to serve files from this folder.

Comment: how can i configure this ?

Answer (score 0):

Use absolute path is not good practice for image URL.

You should configure image path in `web config` or move image to a `CDN` and use it.

In web config

```
<appSettings>
   <add key="BaseImageUrl" value="/Content/Images" />
</appSettings>
```

In cshtml

```
@{
    var FileName = db.UserImages.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserID == User.Identity.Name).ImgName;
    var baseUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BaseImageUrl"];
    var imagePath = string.Format("{0}/{1}", baseUrl, FileName);
}

<img src="@imagePath" class="user-image" alt="User Image"/>
```

You also should move code to get FileName to controller or Service layer should not code in UI layer.